# How to return StatusCode with an explicit header?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

If I do this

```
Response.Headers.Add("Location", $"{baseUrl}/api/v1/User/user/{existingUser.Id}");
return StatusCode(303, new CreateUserResponse() { Id = existingUser.Id, Email = existingUser.Email });
```

It returns a 200 and the Location header is missing.

If I omit setting the Location header, it returns a 303.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, it really is returning a 303 and then automatically redirecting using the Location.